# Adding users automatically to AD domain through G Suite

Tags: active-directory, g-suite, entra-id

Okay, I don't really think this is possible, but I just want to ask:

Is it at all possible to have a user be automatically added to an AD domain whenever they sign into their Google Account in a browser?

These computers are not managed by us in anyway (currently), are likely running Win10 Home, and are not joined to any AD domain.

If this isn't possible with AD, what about Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

you can automatically add or remove user accounts from Azure Active  Directory (Azure AD) to G Suite.
In G Suite we only synchronize existing accounts to other apps or we can create into G Suite.

Prerequisite:

-Azure AD
-G Suite single sign-on enabled
-Google Apps or Google Cloud Platform.

Note:
1.user names created in AD test1@shadow.onmicrosoft.com & test2@shadow.onmicrosoft.com are not accepted by G Suite.
In G suite test1@shadow.com is accepted

2.The custom domain must match the domain name of the source Azure AD or Implement attribute mapping customization. (test.com - test.co)

Steps

1.Enable API access (Admin Console -> Security).

2.Create a custom domain or in G suite account.

3.Create DNS records at any DNS hosting provider for AD
  (i.e) - Azure AD -> Domain -> ADD -> Domain Verification ->  edit the domain's DNS records according to the values that are provided on this page.

4.Create an account with admin role associated with  the necessary API privileges.(Make sure to enable all Admin API Privileges so that this account can be used for provisioning).

5.Configure Azure AD integration with G Suite. 
(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/google-apps-tutorial)

6.In Azure AD -> Select your instance of G Suite -> select the Provisioning.

7.Provisioning Mode to Automatic ->  Admin Credentials section, select Authorize.

8.IN Mappings section, select Synchronize Azure Active Directory Users to Google Apps.

Thanks,